# Python3 - Generate associative array with same key name

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Consider below loop, that loops through each page in a PDF, reads the text and then further divide the PDF page into used-defined column positions:

The column positions are defined like this (through the command line):

```
'{"1":{"position":"15"}, "2":{"position": "20"}}'
```

This is my script:

```py
npages = 2  # Number of pages in the PDF.
column = {}


for n in range(npages):

    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS):
        out = [...] #The specific text from the PDF page, inside the defined column area
        column[i+1] = ({"row": str(out)})
```

Now, consider that I have a PDF file that is two pages long. It contains below text:

## Page 1:

```
Page 1 Col 1 Text                 Page 1 Col 2 Text
```

## Page 2:

```
Page 2 Col 1 Text                 Page 2 Col 2 Text
```

Currently, my code will output below:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "row":"Page 2 \u2013 Col 1.\n\n\f"
   },
   "2":{  
      "row":"Page 2 \u2013 Col 2\n\n\f"
   }
}
```

So, ideally what I want to do, is to generate a JSON output, that looks like below:

```
{  
   "1":[  
      {  
         "row":"Page 1 Col 1 Text"
      },
      {  
         "row":"Page 2 Col 1 Text"
      }
   ],
   "2":[  
      {  
         "row":"Page 1 Col 2 Text"
      },
      {  
         "row":"Page 2 Col 2 Text"
      }
   ],
}
```

So basically, the boundaries of the column will be shared across all pages - and the content of each column must be added to the correct column index, and on each `\n` new line of `out`, it should further be added to a `row` index inside the column index.

Is this even possible with Python3? Would I be better of to save the text content of the PDF files, and then create the JSON string based on each file in a folder?

Comment: Could you provide a better example? I am thinking of e.g. dumping the text you have in your PDF into a `str` and to have your code written with that as starting point. It will be so much easier to get help with that.

Comment: @norok2 the actual PDF file I am testing with actually does contain the content that I have written in my example (`page 1 col 1 text page 1 col 2 text \n page 2 col 1 text page 2 col 2 text`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else in your example works - Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for `column` and append your info.:

```
import collections
column = collections.defaultdict(list)
for n in range(npages):
    for i, col in enumerate(COLUMNS,1):
        out = [...] #The specific text from the PDF page, inside the defined column area
        column[i].append({"row": str(out)})
```

Comment: Just saw it! It works great - I have been banging my head on this for 2 days now. Thanks! Just one thing - how would I be able to dynamically add a new `row` within the column index, if the string splits into a new line? `\n`. Basically what I am trying to do, is to create parse the string and create a "table-like output"

Comment: Just a thought: Would it make sense to make a loop inside the `for i, col` loop? Something like `for newline in out:` and then inside this loop, append the `row:str(out)` ?

Comment: Sounds like a new/different question and it isn't clear, better explore that and  ask another one.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear in my original question, but I did include it. But thanks anyways, your code really helped me! :)

Comment: I think this is a one question per question site but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah OK! No worries :)